# Can somebody explain the following RegEx(Python) code for me?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
def clean_tweet(self, tweet):
     return ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", tweet).split())
```

What is the use of join() and split() function?
What does the ' ' after return mean?

Answer (score 1):

```
(...)|(...)|(...)
```

Means first or second or third regex between parenthesis.

```
@[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

Matches "@" followed by any series of letters (small or big) and digits. '+' means longest possible match of this series, matching at least 1.

```
[^0-9A-Za-z \t]
```

A single digit, That mustn't be (`^` inside `[]`) one of: letter (big or mall), space or tab. One character only.

```
\w+:\/\/\S+
```

`\w+` means longest possible match of letters (at least one), followed by ':', followed by // (you need to escape a /). Finally `\S`+ matches longest match and at least one of a non-space character.

Comment: @LukStorms Correct you are, missed it and thanks.